# Algorithm for finding object in range without looping through all other objects?

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

**Background:**

I'm in the beginning of making a game, it has objects that should be able to communicate with each-other by "sound" (not necessarily real sound, can be simulated sound, but it should behave like sound).

That means that they can only communicate with each-other if they are within hearing-range.

**Question:**

*Is there some smart way to test if a another object is within hearing-range without having to loop through all of the other objects?* (it would become really inefficient when it's a lot of them).

**Note:** There can be more than 1 object within hearing-range, so all objects within hearing-range are added to an array (or list, haven't decided yet) for communication.

**Data**

Currently the object has these properties (it can be changed if needed).

```
Object {
    id = self.id,
    x = self.x,
    y = self.y,
    hearing_max_range = random_range(10, 20), // eg: 10
    can_hear_other = []; // append: other.id when in other in range
}
```

Comment: What languages / engines are you using?

Comment: Bin your objects by square bins of width `hearing_range`. Then just iterate through the 9 surrounding bins comparing distance.

Comment: @molamk For now I'm making a prototype in Game Maker, but I might switch language later if this works as I hope. But the language doesn't really matter, use whatever you're comfortable with, I understand most programming languages, I just need to know what I should do to make it work without looping through everything.

Comment: @DillonDavis Like a virtual checkerboard? something like: 
`bin_size = 10;` `index = floor(self.x / bin_size);` `global_bin_x[ index ] = self.id;` 
and then do the same for Y and check whatever entries is in `index+1 & -1` if they are in range?

Comment: @SebastianNorr essentially yes. I would use a dictionary indexed by `(self.x//bin_size, self.y//bin_size)` tuples, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: You could also look into quadtrees or kd-trees, but binning will probably be simpler and faster as long as it doesn't waste too much memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into some clever data structures such as quadtrees or kd-trees, but for a problem with a fixed range query, it might not be too bad to just use simple binning. I'll present the general algorithm in python-like pseudo code.

First construct your bins:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

def make_bin(game_objects, bin_size):
    object_bins = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in game_objects:
        object_bins[(obj.x//bin_size, obj.y//bin_size)].append(obj)
```

Then query as necessary:

```python
def find_neighbors(game_object, object_bins, bin_size):
    x_idx = game_object.x // bin_size
    y_idx = game_object.y // bin_size
    for x_bin in range(x_idx - 1, x_idx + 2):
        for y_bin in range(y_idx - 1, y_idx + 2):
            for obj in object_bins[(x_bin, y_bin)]:
                if (obj.x - game_object.x)**2 + (obj.y - game_object.y)**2 <= bin_size**2:
                    yield obj
```